# In lecture 4a pattern matching what is the colon?

Tags: scheme

I just started watching lecture 4a sicp,  I am completely lost. It seemed the difficulty ramped up from lecture 3 to 4.  Are these lectures on youtube out of order with the current MIT course? http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-001-structure-and-interpretation-of-computer-programs-spring-2005/lecture-notes/

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=amf5lTZ0UTc&index=7&list=PL8FE88AA54363BC46

Can someone explain to me what the general process that he's doing?   I haven't been reading the book, just viewing the videos on youtube. Should I stop watching the videos and just read the book and do every single exercise along the way?

What is the (: x1) and (? x2) for?

```
(define deriv-rules
    '(
        ( (dd (?c c) (? v))         0)
        ( (dd (?v v) (? v))         1)
        ( (dd (?v u) (? v))         0)

        ; Derivative of (+ x1 x2) in respect to v
        ( (dd (+ (? x1) (? x2)) (? v))
            (+
                (dd (: x1) (: v))
                (dd (: x2) (: v))
            )
        )

        ; Derivative of (* x1 x2) in respect to v
        ( (dd (* (? x1) (? x2)) (? v))
            (+
                (* (: x1) (dd (: x2) (: v)))
                (* (dd (: x1) (: v)) (: x2))
            )
        )

        ; Derivative of x^(const) in respect to v
        ( (dd (** (? x) (?c n)) (? v))
            (*
                (* (: n) (** (: x) (: (- n 1))))
                (dd (: x) (: v))
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: -1 The title asks about colon and pattern matching, but the question doesn't say anything about them.  If you have questions about the code in the lectures, please reproduce at least enough of the relevant code in the question.  If your question is about the lectures/book/course relationship, then ask about that, not some particular part of the code.

Comment: Just in case, [here](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-001-structure-and-interpretation-of-computer-programs-spring-2005/video-lectures) is the correct order of the video lectures

Comment: I've removed my downvote, since you've added the code.  The colon is explained at 11:37 of the video in the last link that you posted. The question mark is explained a bit earlier.  Se 12:10 for the definitions of some rules that use both.

Comment: In my opinion, you should continue watching the videos, and *also* read the book *and* do every exercise. Contrary to many other books, SICP contains a lot of learning and understanding in the exercises, even the ones that look simple or trivial at first.

Answer (score 0):

The colon is explained at 11:37 of the video in the last link that you posted. The question mark is explained a bit earlier.  Let's look at this code:

```
(define deriv-rules
    '(
        ( (dd (?c c) (? v))         0)                ; 1
        ( (dd (?v v) (? v))         1)                ; 2
        ( (dd (?v u) (? v))         0)                ; 3

        ; Derivative of (+ x1 x2) in respect to v
        ( (dd (+ (? x1) (? x2)) (? v))                ; 4
            (+
                (dd (: x1) (: v))
                (dd (: x2) (: v))
            )
        )
…
```

`deriv-rules` is a a list of lists, each of the form `(pattern derivative)`.  For instance, rules 1, 2, and 3, say, respectively:

- The derivative of a constant *c* with respect to any thing (call it *v*) is 0.
- The derivative of any variable *v* with respect to *v* is 1.
- The derivative of any variable *u* with respect to anything (call it *v*) is 0.

There's no use of colon in those, because none of those derivatives require instantiation.  However rule 4 says taht the derivative of a sum *x<sub>1</sub> + x<sub>2</sub>* with respect to any *v* is the sum of the derivative of *x<sub>1</sub>* with respect to *v* and the derivative of *x<sub>2</sub>* with respect to *v*.  The `(: …)` notation provides a way to refer to the value of the variable `…`.

Comment: Thank you Joshua. I'm going to have the rewatch the video again but I'm not getting it.

Comment: Can you elaborate?  The rules alone are just a big list, and require some other program to interpret them, but the gist of the thing is that some symbolic differentiator will try to match an expression against the patterns in these rules, and will return an instance of the template from the rules.